# How to take two single and two word inputs from the input file

Tags: java

I have the input file which looks something like this:

```
Cinema 1 A 15
Cinema 2 X 5
Session 1 09:00 Toy Story
Session 1 14:30 Ratatouille
Session 2 09:00 Up
Request 1 1 09:00 10
Request 2 1 09:00 12
Request 3 1 09:00 10
Change 1 1 14:30 7 
Cancel 6
Print 1 14:30
```

wherein Session 1 09:00 and Toy Story are 4 different inputs for Session, Cinema Number, time and the movie.

I am having an issue with extracting the last input as some inputs have two words and some has one.

To get only one word, i am using the split() method.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));

            while(sc.hasNext()){
                String param = sc.nextLine();
                String[] in = param.split(" ");
                ......

                ......
            }
```

which gives me an output like:
[image]

As we can see, the output only has Toy in it.

How can I fix this?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Since you are splitting on the empty space characters, titles such as "Toy Story" would return more than one token. If you are confident that the cinema title is always on a fixed position, you can list the tokens up to that position (e.g. from in[1] to in[2]) and as title take everything rest (from in[3] to in[in.size()]

Comment: We can help better if you post all the code. It is not clear to us how you get your *output*. There are many ways to do this...

Comment: Hi @Bghaak , I have now changed the input file ( i had only put partial before). Would you guys mind having a look now? Thanks :)

Comment: i am using split on each line and then each element is used as inputs for different functionalities in the program